# Can I change the behavior of Code::Blocks auto-indent?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, editor, codeblocks, indentation

I used to use Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 to write C++ code, and the behavior of auto-indent in it was very good.

But when I tried to use Code::Blocks, I realized that the behavior of auto-indent in it is awful.

for example one of the things that bother me:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
//it start from here in Code::Blocks

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    //I want it to start from here like in Visual Studio
```

the same thing for `if` and `while`

Is there any way to change the behavior of auto-indent in Code::Blocks so it'll be as good as Microsoft Visual Studio auto-indent?

Comment: What specifically are the differences that bother you?

Comment: At least as far as I could figure out the last time I tried, the answer seemed to be no -- but C::B's editor configuration was sufficiently confused and confusing that it would be essentially impossible to be sure.

Comment: There is a setting in Editor Settings 'Smart Indent'. But it's kind of buggy.. Sometimes it works correctly sometimes doesn't. I couldn't understand what is going on. Tried it carefully in same cases. I'm using CB 12.11 .

Answer (score 11):

First, make sure `smart indent` is enabled (Settings -> Editor -> Smart indent).

It still wasn't working for me on Ubuntu, but installing the `codeblocks-contrib` package with

```
sudo apt-get install codeblocks-contrib
```

fixed some of the problems.  It fixed the smart-indenting for `if`, `while`, `for`, but not for classes and functions.  If anyone knows how to fix the rest of problem, please let me know.

Comment: Well, it also fix the smart-indenting for the classes and function as I tested on ubuntu16.04,  codeblocks 13.12+dfsg-4, just now.