# C++ code::block curly bracket style

Tags: c++, eclipse, rstudio

A novice here who has some experience in Rstudio.

I really like where in R studio, the curly bracket can be positioned automatically like this when i type `{` and hit Enter:

```
abc <- function(x){
  blablabla
  return(bla)
}
```

Apparently if I use Eclipse IDE for C++ this style is also available, but I can't deal with the compiler problem (where iostream has or has not unresolved inclusion depend solely on the mood of Eclipse or the weather) so i use code::block instead.

But in code::block, if i do the same thing, the following would happen:

```
int main(){
blablabla
return(bla)
}
```

i.e. the content of the function would not have the space at their front, which kills the readability.

The only way code::block may have this space, as far as i know, is to do the following:

```
int main()
{
  blablabla
  return(bla)
}
```

Which include hitting Enter before hitting `{` and this honestly drives me crazy.

Is there any way to customise code::block such that the Rstudio style curly bracket can be achieved?

Comment: Have you considered making R studio to use aligned brackets style?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I change the behavior of Code::Blocks auto-indent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712846/can-i-change-the-behavior-of-codeblocks-auto-indent)

Comment: code::blocks is barely supported. Not sure if your problem with Eclipse is of your own doing (i.e. wrong includes) or it's and IDE configuration problem (maybe it's better to ask question regarding that), but if you need an alternative powerful cross-platform C++ IDE I'd suggest Qt Creator. It also has convenient format configuration.

Comment: I'm not sure why beginners continue to use Code::Blocks. There are many better IDEs out there. The JetBrains IDEs (CLion for C/C++) are really good, in general. If you are a student, you can get them for free with your university email address.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the [clang-format](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) utility. It has a variety of style options ([see documentation here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html)).

It'll bring auto-format capability inline with what you've seen in Code::blocks.

While I'm not an Eclipse user, it looks like the [CppStyle plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/cppstyle) will do the trick.

In order to get your IDE to automatically format your code, you simply need to create a `.clang-format` file in your user accounts home directory e.g. `/home/noodle` and configure which ever plugin you use to format on save.

Here's what mine looks like:

```
$ cat ~/.clang-format
BasedOnStyle: google
IndentWidth: 2
```

There are a variety of style options, but it looks like you'd want to follow the [Google C++ style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html), which places the curly brace on the same line as the condition statement/for-loop etc.